# overlay images as transparent layers with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I want to stack several images using imagemagick. The result I want is the same as I get when I import all images as layers into Gimp and set the layer transparency to some value.

Each image is transparent with a circle in the center of various sizes. Overlaying all N images with a 100/N% opacity should give me something like a blurry blob with radially increasing transparency. Here are three example images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

However if I try to do this with imagemagick, I get a black background:

```
convert image50.png -background transparent -alpha set -channel A -fx "0.2" \( image60.png -background transparent -alpha set -channel A -fx "0.2" \) -compose overlay -composite -flatten result.png
```

Edit:
After Mark Setchells latest comments, I got

[image]

What I want is that those areas that appear in all images (the center in the example) add up to to non-transparent region, while those regions that appear only on fewer images get more and more transparent. Marks example seems to work for 3 images, but not for a larger stack. The result I would like to get would be this one (here I emphasize the transparent regions by adding a non-white background):

[image]

The example images are made from this one

[image]

using this bash command:

```
for i in $(seq 10 10 90); do
    f="image$i.png"
    convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjWgF.png -quality 100 -fuzz $i% -fill white -transparent black $f
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Calculate how many images we have
N=$(ls image*.png|wc -l)
echo N:$N

# Generate mask, start with black and add in components from each subsequent image
i=0
convert image10.png -evaluate set 0 mask.png
for f in image*png;do
   convert mask.png \( "$f" -alpha extract -evaluate divide $N \) -compose plus -composite mask.png 
done

# Generate output image
convert image*.png      \
   -compose overlay -composite \
   mask.png -compose copy-opacity -composite out.png
```

Comment: Not quite what I want - see edits above. The background is still dark for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I will try the different transparency setting, but still, the background tends to become black with the code you sent - please compare the corners of my desired output (they are white due to transparency) with the output of your command (which is a semi-transparent black). Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: I think I have got it... try first command in my answer please.

Comment: above was just an example with 3 images, I am really using many more and the result doesn't look as I want it to. Do you know how to do the plain adding of transparent layers as explained above?

Comment: Please have another look.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. I think we're almost there but I think the multiply doesn't work for many images. I added code to generate the example image.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work how I intended but I think this gets closer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a different mode of compositing. You were using `-compose overlay` which is going  to lighten up the result with each successive layer. What you probably want here is `-compose blend` to keep only the most saturated value or or just `-compose over` to layer them with no modifications.